# Howto use a GUID as an ADO query parameter using C++ ADO

Tags: c++, ado, guid, uniqueidentifier, variant

Given a SQL Server database that uses uniqueidentifiers as primary key fields for the table I want to query and a GUID struct (included via rpc.h) that has the value of one of the entries in the table, how do I create a ADODB::Parameter that stores that value?

I understand that the parameters take their values as _variant_t. How do I get from the GUID to a _variant_t? A cast produces an error and the _variant_t type does not take a GUID in the constructor.

I am creating the command and parameter objects in the following way:

```
HRESULT hr;
_CommandPtr selectCmd;
hr = selectCmd.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Command));
if (FAILED(hr))
    throw _com_error(hr);

selectCmd->CommandText = L"SELECT .... WHERE id=@id";
selectCmd->Parameters->Append(selectCmd->CreateParameter(L"@id",DataTypeEnum::adGUID, ParameterDirectionEnum::adParamInput, 16, /* what to put here? */));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a string, formatted with curly braces.  If you have the guid value stored in a variable of type System.Guid then you can use the "B" format specifier.  Like this:

```
  var arg = guid.ToString("B");
```

See [this web page](http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-46121.html) for reference.

Oops, that's C# code, you can generate the string in C++ by using StringFromIID().

Comment: Found the anser in the referenced web page. Thanks.

Comment: It is not the correct answer. The code is in c++. The parameter type expected here is a VARIANT that contains Guid information.